# Creating "floating" widget like volume / brightness

Tags: android, mobile, user-interface

How can I create a UI that can be launched much like the volume / brightness widget and can accept user input and automagically hides if clicked outside the view?

The best that I could do was use `WindowManager::addView` but that does not hide automagically.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@android:style/Theme.Dialog` to have your entire `Activity` act as a dialog.

Alternatively, use a `DialogFragment`. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) for details on how to use a custom layout style.

**EDIT**

Another option, which provides more control over placement/behavior is to use a transparent `Activity` and simply create the widget like you would any other. You would set your theme to something like:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

Then, create your layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/floating_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:drawable/panel_background" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can add margins to the `floating_panel` if you know where you always want it, or set the placement programmatically.

If none of this works, check out the class [PopupMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html), which uses a `View` as an anchor. Perhaps you could use it as a starting point. Similarly, look into [PopupWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html), using `showAtLocation(View, int, int, int)` to set the placement.

Many options available. Just depends on what type of behavior your looking for.

Comment: But you can't control the placement of the dialog, or can you?

Comment: Hmm... `PopupWindow` looks interesting. let me give a shot

Comment: I noticed that to "show" the `PopupWindow`, I'll always need a `View` to anchor around. I'm looking at a more "free float" option much like volume control that has no access to my "view" and loads the UI

Comment: Provided 4 or 5 options here. If you don't want an anchor, use my second approach (translucent `Activity`).

Comment: Sadly, that does not allow interaction with the stuff "beneath" the activity.

Comment: Put a click listener on the surrounding layout (the translucent background) and dismiss the "dialog" when it's touched.

Comment: That "eats" the touch. I mean, if there's an EditText beneath this, this should hide and EditText should get the focus.